# Problem with making Binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to make:

```
data BinTree a b = b | Branch a (BinTree a b) (BinTree a b) deriving Show
```

But there is an error that `b` is not a data constructor. How can i fix that because i want my tree to always return b type.

Answer (score 4):

> How can i fix that because i want my tree to always return b type.

You need to define a *data constructor* that wraps the `b` value:

```
data BinTree a b = Leaf b | Branch a (BinTree a b) (BinTree a b) deriving Show
```

Then in functions where you obtain leaves, you can use pattern matching to "unwrap" the value out of the `Leaf` data constructor.

For example you can obtain a list of the values wrapped in the leaves for a `BinTree a b` with:

```
leaves :: BinTree a b -> [b]
leaves (Leaf b) = [b]
leaves (Branch _ la lb) = leaves la ++ leaves lb
```

Comment: Oh i haven't thought about that. Thank you

Comment: can you give me an example how i can "unwrap" the value out?

Answer (score 3):

You need a data constructor for the leaf; the type alone isn't not sufficient.

```
data BinTree a b = Leaf b | Branch a (BinTree a b) (BinTree a b)
```

Is there a reason you allow leaves and interior nodes to store values of different types? Also, you can't represent an empty tree with this data type. You might want

```
data BinTree a = Empty | Branch a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
```

instead. With this, a leaf is now just a `Branch` value with both children empty: `Branch 3 Empty Empty` instead of `Leaf 3`.

Comment: Huffman encoding: frequencies govern branching, chars are the payload.

Comment: Are the frequencies usually stored in the interior nodes, though? You only need them to build the tree, not to do {en,de}-coding with the tree.

Comment: I mean, once you *have* the tree, you don't need the frequencies. You can keep a separate table of frequencies while building the tree, and discard them when you are done.

Comment: your "Is there a reason you allow leaves and interior nodes to store values of different types? " in the *answer* reads like "you really shouldn't, there's no reason for it". so I provided a counterexample, where such trees *are* useful. (in the *comments* that question would read as just asking for a specific clarification, but not in the answer, I don't think). see e.g. the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). whether it *can* be optimized away, is a separate concern.